# JQ - add element to array and return full json

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to add an element to an array like this:

```
jq --arg root "arn:aws:iam::$ACCOUNT_ID:root" \
              '.Statement[] | select(.Sid=="Allow use of the key") \
              | .Principal.AWS |= . + [$root]' \
 <<<$policy
```

Although this works, it only output the specific section, as I am executing a `select`.

Content of `$policy`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*:root"
      },
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Create*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Enable*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Put*",
        "kms:Update*",
        "kms:Revoke*",
        "kms:Disable*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:Delete*",
        "kms:TagResource",
        "kms:UntagResource"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::*:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:CreateGrant"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*:root"
      },
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Create*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Enable*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Put*",
        "kms:Update*",
        "kms:Revoke*",
        "kms:Disable*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:Delete*",
        "kms:TagResource",
        "kms:UntagResource"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::*:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::$root:root" <-------------
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:CreateGrant"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get back the initial json with the added element?

Comment: post `$policy` contents and expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've added code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassign the `.Statement` array with the new one containing the former entries with the target object updated:

```
jq --arg root "arn:aws:iam::$ACCOUNT_ID:root" \
'.Statement |= map(select(.Sid=="Allow use of the key").Principal.AWS |= . + [$root])' <<<$policy
```

Comment: ^Thank you! I cannot up vote